# How are these conditionals any different?

Tags: javascript, null, conditional-statements, undefined

Why are these 2 conditionals different:

Incorrect:

```
if (myObj !== null && typeof myObj !== "undefined")
```

Because of this, you must test typeof() first:

Correct:

```
if (typeof myObj !== "undefined" && myObj !== null)
```

I pulled this off the w3schools site. According to w3schools you must test the typeof() first, why would this make a difference. The conditions  look to be the same

Comment: This is  a great example of why w3schools information should be taken with a grain of salt.

Comment: It's not the same because && operator is short-circuit: the second condition is not evaluated when the first one is falsy.

Comment: Because if `myObj` is not defined at all, you'll get an error if you don't first check it with typeof.

Comment: To elaborate on my snarky comment, the example is accurate, but I think it's a poor example because it implies that you should write code that way, and I think that's sub-optimal code.

Comment: But an important question - *why* do you need to check if `myObj` exists?

Comment: Generally you don't, but there are cases where you may, is say `JSON`, `Promise` or perhaps `Reflect` declared if not use shim. Feature detection.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first condition will **throw an error** if the variable is undeclared.

`ReferenceError: myObj is not defined`

Note that the && operator is short-circuiting, so in the second condition, the `myObj !== null` expression will not be evaluated at all if myObj is undefined.

See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_mistakes.asp) for details.

Comment: It'll throw an error if the object is *undeclared*; it can be declared and have no value, however, and it won't throw an error then.

Comment: However my answer was wrong anyway; I think I need a nap :)

Comment: @Pointy you are right, undeclared is the correct word to use. I edited my answer.

Comment: I'd say "if the **variable** is undeclared". An object is a *value* but the value is irrelevant in this case.

Comment: Wow. Alright I was held up on that for forever. The way it is worded is confusing. I thought and was thinking of a variable having the undefined value, not being "Not declared" therefore "Not defined"